# Client received SOAP Fault from server: Authentication failed ebay

Tags: java, soap, ebay-api

When I am trying to run java app to look the item from ebay api I am getting exp:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Authentication failed : Invalid Application:app key   Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.findItemsByKeywords(Unknown Source)
    at FindItem.main(FindItem.java:59)
```

I imported 2 jars as written on tutorial but still have this issue,
I get the key from ebay web of app key.
My code is:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.setApplicationId("MY app key that taken from ebay");

//create a service client
FindingServicePortType serviceClient = FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(config);

//create request object
FindItemsByKeywordsRequest request = new FindItemsByKeywordsRequest();
//set request parameters
request.setKeywords("harry potter phoenix");
PaginationInput pi = new PaginationInput();
pi.setEntriesPerPage(2);
request.setPaginationInput(pi);

//call service
FindItemsByKeywordsResponse result = serviceClient.findItemsByKeywords(request);
```

and another question, how can I get specification of the item? 
Hope you can help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the AppID which you given to connect the API is Invalid.

My questions are

1. Do you have DevID, AppID and CertID provided by eBay ?
2. If you have then please try to connect from SOAP UI to check whether it is working.

Comment: maybe you can send some URL to get this from, like they have some build url to get the info from it, its looks better.

Comment: Please do register in this url and it will guide you to proceed.
https://go.developer.ebay.com/